# Why is my XML Http request not executing anything?

Tags: javascript

I have a XML http requests but for some reason it doesn't work. It is supposed to check the number of friends the person has then if there aren't enough displayed you know, do all that stuff. And don't worry, I checked the database and all the sql, it removes/adds friends successfully but the problem is that the console says it executes it but the function doesn't do anything

Here is the function :

```
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("numoffriends");
    numoffriends = x.length;
    var fullurl = "../backend/friends.php?numoffriends=" + numoffriends + "&loadfriends=true";
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("GET", fullurl , false);
      request.onload = function(){
          if(request.status == 200){
              let testdivvv = document.createElement("element");
              testdivvv.innerHTML = this.responseText;
              groupchat = document.getElementById("leftsmallbox");
                groupchat.append(testdivvv);
          }
      }
      request.send();
    }
    setInterval(loadfriends, 1500);
```

If it makes any difference there are also 4 other functions on the same timing i.e gets executed. I checked, there is indeed an object called leftsmallbox.

If you have any questions just ask, I'll be available for a while

Comment: Any errors that are in the console?

Comment: weirdly enough no

Comment: Use the Network tab of DevTools to see the request that's being sent and the response.

Comment: it said this respnse has no data available

Comment: Try your code using a Fake Online REST API like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com